# Defining operator on the cartesian product

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V, W$ be Hilbert spaces with inner products $(\cdot, \cdot)_V$, $(\cdot, \cdot)_W$ respectively, and $A\,\colon V\rightarrow V, B\,\colon W\rightarrow W$. Denote $X=V\times W$ with canonical inner product.

Can we define $T\,\colon X \rightarrow X$

$$(Tx,y)_{X}=(Au,v)_{V}+(Bw,z)_{W}$$

for all $x=(u,w)\in V\times W$ and $y=(v,z)\in V\times W$? Does it exist in such a form?

Comment: Why not? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Because I don't give a formula $Tx=...$ but instead I demand to satisfy a condtition above given by the inner product.

Comment: Thanks to riesz representation theorem, every continuous bilinear form on a Hilbert space $H$ has the form $(Tx, y)$ for a suitable continuous operator $T$ on $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $A,B$ are bounded linear operators, consider the operator $A\oplus B$ on $X$, defined by
$$A\oplus B(u,w):=(Au,Bw),$$
where $u\in V,\;w\in W$. Clearly, this is a bounded linear operator. Now look at the inner product
$$
\begin{split}
    \langle A\oplus B(u,w) , (v,z) \rangle_X &=\langle Au,v\rangle_V + \langle Bw , y \rangle_W.
\end{split}
$$
Thus, if we define $Tx:= (A\oplus B )(x)$, this $T$ satisfies the equation 
$$\langle T(u,w),(v,z)\rangle_X=\langle Au,v\rangle_V + \langle Bw , y \rangle_W$$
and non-degeneracy of the scalar product implies that $T$ is the unique operator satisfying this equation.

This not only settles the existence of $T$, but gives an explicit formula.